# Does Saml2SecurityTokenHandler support SAML2 assertions signed using SHA256?

Tags: c#, certificate, saml-2.0

**TL;DR**: Can anyone find an authority on which signature algorithms are supported by `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler` during validation?

---

I'm using a `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler` to verify SAML assertions from my IdP.

For reference, I am using a sample assertion signed with **SHA256** found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133771(v=sc.12).aspx)

```
<Assertion ID="_de9f29bd-52ca-4237-95c1-eb53f70fe8e5" IssueInstant="2012-11-06T00:45:30.593Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<Issuer>ADatum</Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
        <ds:Reference URI="#_de9f29bd-52ca-4237-95c1-eb53f70fe8e5">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>+6OWUn1dFIUJQ6FQ25zgmZvg8zPzfcjnj4ujUvgfmEQ=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>O85ytS9fcAhOk/0K25SndyBUbNLrx6J+tv+Uht+HZZ4CzsqjVBU1FpkXjDG03HqZ7xEu3+rMnsyxefDq6Xftw1E926QsG/oPM/afWfbR5dLucjsVaNzXCXzZu+jBmp5KkAv/vv1Es67KnPMr/RDeCVFy9eyxJka6dd8h8RTlatg=</ds:SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>MIICGjCCAYOgAwIBAgIQeJe5qR+4T6VJNZYtWjhErzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADAgMR4wHAYDVQQDExVBQ1MyQ2xpZW50Q2VydGlmaWNhdGUwHhcNMTExMDEwMDcwMDAwWhcNNDExMjMxMDcwMDAwWjAgMR4wHAYDVQQDExVBQ1MyQ2xpZW50Q2VydGlmaWNhdGUwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAKjtrnJ+bduREosQ9+SH1ocI13wlxStLi8y5heGPo5UBcuf0hYRq4PvjwEY2twebP6iwxjwGqhu224UDUfPWMhQBOh+NFnv9GHAh+W4jFJxvTCcyXTkZRFqgAYRjMvyxzNeHVqn4AJ/ddKGf1fMVCuKhPYteHy2yNacXujucPP6/AgMBAAGjVTBTMFEGA1UdAQRKMEiAEFD3/7uhGcI2nSHZqB0bN66hIjAgMR4wHAYDVQQDExVBQ1MyQ2xpZW50Q2VydGlmaWNhdGWCEHiXuakfuE+lSTWWLVo4RK8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEEBQADgYEAkgxktVU5e8TVoigsDRm4qyw6gM/kie3e6dFM0T1BFoQV0PW9W9yKPiP72eTi+331tLFnwDxz5RJLABctAO71plwtREd0k3E0Jsju+Web+u8YcCD43aViQXgXRrY5ghDGwpFRcaNa1PnYY5nk3DYfyZZdz1L+fb30VDiugdf7dBI=</X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<Subject>
    <NameID>ADatum</NameID>
    <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer" />
</Subject>
<Conditions NotBefore="2012-11-06T00:45:31.905Z" NotOnOrAfter="9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z">
    <AudienceRestriction>
        <Audience>https://accesscontrol.adatum.com</Audience>
    </AudienceRestriction>
</Conditions>
<AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/spf/2012/03/claims/tenantname">
        <AttributeValue>Fabrikam</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
<AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role">
        <AttributeValue>SSU</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
<AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn">
        <AttributeValue>accesscontrol@adaum.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
```

I have the following code attempting to verify this signature

```
//All that matters now is to validate the token and get the claims
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters();
validationParameters.ValidIssuer = options.Issuer;
validationParameters.ValidAudience = options.Audience;
validationParameters.IssuerSigningToken = new X509SecurityToken(options.SigningCertificate);
validationParameters.ValidateLifetime = validateLifetime;
validationParameters.TokenReplayCache = options.ReplayRepository;

EnsureCanonicalForm(response, assertion);

SecurityTokenHandlerCollection coll = SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionExtensions.GetDefaultHandlers();
SecurityToken tokenOut;
var retVal = coll.ValidateToken(assertion.OuterXml, validationParameters, out tokenOut);
```

`options.SigningCertificate` is the certificate you can see in the XML starting with `MII...`. `assertion.OuterXml` is the entire contents of the XML above.

I was expecting the `SAML2SecurityTokenHandler` to handle **SHA256**, but this code fails on `ValidateToken()` with the error

> The signature verification failed.

I know the code works for SHA1 using the same code with a different assertion sample.

I wasn't able to find any mention of signing algorithms in the documentation around either [the handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.saml2.saml2securitytokenhandler.aspx) or [the token itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.saml2.saml2securitytoken.aspx), but at least [one of the specs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4051.txt) for XML signature hashing does call-out SHA256.

Can anyone find an authoritative source on which signature algorithms are supported by this class?

Comment: I'm able to recall testing sha256 with SAML 2

Comment: I can confirm that SHA256 is not a problem in SAML2 assertions. We have it implemented in several projects using IdentityServer v2 as STS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler` doesn't handle white spaces correctly when validating the signature. In most cases it doesn't matter as assertions are rarely pretty printed. But this one is. So I guess that's the problem.

For the SAML library I've created we completely skip the signature validation in the handler and do our own based on `SignedXml` instead, which is more reliable (although you need to remember to check the references yourself).

Comment: Pretty print will invalidate signature of almost any signed xml because it destroys the original document (with the exception when original document was already pretty printed). You can not tell what did the document look like because canonicalization scheme does not take into consideration white spaces. It is not IMHO possible to compute correct hash of the document that was signed and therefore it is not possible to verify the integrity/signature of the document.

Comment: Pretty printing *after* calculating the signature invalidates it yes. But the `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler` has problems if an XML document containing white space (e.g. pretty printed) is signed.